# enabling fastcgi mod in lighttpd through puppet

Tags: puppet

Hi guys am new to puppet and I want to execute the following command on client using puppet so that the fast cgi mod is enabled on the puppet client.
    lighttpd-enable-mod fastcgi

Both puppet server and client are ubuntu machines and my lighttpd module's init.pp file is as follows:

```
class lighttpd::install {
package { "lighttpd":
ensure => present,
}
 }

class lighttpd::conf {
file { "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf":
    ensure => present,
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => 0600,
    source => "puppet:///modules/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf",
    require => Class["lighttpd::install"],
    }
}


class lighttpd::fastcgi {
file { "/etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-fastcgi.conf":
    ensure => present,
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => 0600,
    source => "puppet:///modules/lighttpd/10-fastcgi.conf",
    require => Class["lighttpd::install"],
    }

}

class lighttpd {
include lighttpd::install, lighttpd::conf, lighttpd::fastcgi
```

}

Please help me execute this command on the puppet client.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you modify your lighttpd::fastcgi class to be something like:

```
class lighttpd::fastcgi {
  file { "/etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-fastcgi.conf":
    ensure => present,
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => 0600,
    source => "puppet:///modules/lighttpd/10-fastcgi.conf",
    require => Class["lighttpd::install"],
    notify => Exec["enable-mod-fastcgi"],
  }
  exec { "enable-mod-fastcgi":
    command => "/usr/bin/lighttpd-enable-mod fastcgi",
    refreshonly => true,
  }
}
```

(sorry - the path may be wrong to lighttpd-enable-mod - I don't have lighttpd here).

This should notify the 'exec' correctly. The exec will only get called when notified because of the 'refreshonly' parameter being true.